# Ubuntu: Prevent X from starting (turn desktop into server)

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine that's been setup as a desktop; it starts X and the full UI. I only need it as a server (will be accessing it via ssh) and am looking to reduce the memory footprint.

What's a good way to prevent X from starting when the machine boots?

Update: ended up going with:

```
sudo mv /etc/rc2.d/S30gdm /etc/disabled-S30gdm
```

via the link in Evan Anderson's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Ubuntu (I'm a CentOS / Fedora guy), but typically this is done with runlevels. I'm reading that, at least on Ubuntu "Gutsy", there isn't a runlevel that doesn't start X by default. What a pain!

Have a look at this guy's site-- it should at least give you an idea of where to look. http://caulfield.info/emmet/2008/03/add-a-textonly-runlevel-to-ubu.html

On RedHat-style distributions this would be easy...  >smile<

I dunno about these techniques above to remove GDM, but I'd rather be able to select a different runlevel to get X back than go removing software.

Edit: Here's some potentially better thoughts: http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2008/07/02/enabledisable-gdm-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Ubuntu's runlevels 2-5 all start with a GUI (IIRC) and they lack the inittab that Redhat/Fedora/CentOS has in favor of upstart

Comment: That's what I meant when I said "I'm reading that ... there isnt' a runlevel that doesn't start X by default!"

Answer (score 5):

You can disable GDM by:

```
update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

Then re-boot and you should have your console window.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System -> Administration -> Services and disable GDM

Comment: Looks like there's no Services option under Administration. There's a "Login Window" option that lets me set the "Default Session" to "Secure remote connection" or "Failsafe Terminal", are either of those what I'm looking for?

Comment: You should be seeing configuration options like this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/prevent-xorg-from-starting-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu there is a config file for gdm at

```
/etc/init/gdm.conf
```

The lines you will want to alter are:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
```

to be more like:

```
start on runlevel []
stop on runlevel [0123456] # you can leave some runlevels in the start on line if you know what runlevel you are currently running on.
```

you can always get the gdm to run once you login using the command `startx`.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305659

Comment: Unfortunately 11.04 has changed that.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Ubuntu, but in RedHat/Fedora/CentOS, you just change the default runlevel in /etc/inittab to 3

```
id:3:initdefault:
```